# Validate a column only if another column is not blank - Excel Formula not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column-formula, list-validation

I need to add a column validation to my list.

The requirement for the validation is that the column [Body] cant be empty if the column [Status] is one of this statuses: "1-Cancelled" or "2-Awaiting Information from Requester".

I tested the below formula in Excel which is working, but not working in the SharePoint.

```
=NOT(
AND(
OR(
[Status]="1-Cancelled",[Status]="2-Awaiting Information from Requester"), ISBLANK([Body])
))
```

Please help me to find the right formula. Thanks in advance

Comment: I tried the following formula, but it is not working: =IF(AND(ISBLANK([Body])=TRUE,[Status]="1-Cancelled"),FALSE,TRUE)

Comment: What is the data type of [Body] column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below formula:

```
=IF(OR([Status]="1-Cancelled",[Status]="2-Awaiting Information from Requester"),IF(ISBLANK([Body]), false, true), true)
```

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (I am not sure but it is based on something language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Also note that it is not possible to achieve using validation formulas if [Body] is Multiple lines of text field.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ganesh. I got an error: "The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported."

Comment: Oops... Try updated formula in my answer. Also you need to add this formula in List Settings-->Validation settings.

Comment: Thanks Ganesh. I also tried replacing all the comma with semicolon, but I got the same error, I have other validations with commas. I tried on the "validation settings" on the List settings, but I got a different error: "One or more column references are not allowed, because the columns are defined as a data type that is not supported in formulas." [Status] is a choice and [Body] is Multiple lines of text

Comment: Yes, if body is multiple lines of text then it is not possible using validation settings to achieve what you want because formulas don't support multiple lines of text field.

Comment: OK, so the only choice is to change the type of [Body]. But I need to leave it long to allow many comments back of for, so I think i wont be able to use the formula.                              Thanks for your help Ganesh

Comment: Yes, it is not possible using formulas. Please [Upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you.

Comment: I found a workaround to solve this problem. Change the column [Body] to single text, apply the validation and then change the type again to multiple text. I will upvote, your answer helped me